# Google OAuth 2.0 doesn't call the callback function

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I've tested this passport google strategy locally and it works well, the callback function is called successfully and I can login using the google account. However when I push this code to the production server I see that the callback function is not being called. From the user perspective when they click on the link to use the google strategy they are presented with the google 'pick an account' screen, and then it loads for a bit before dumping them back on the page they were on before. I don't see where the problem is. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
passport.use('google', new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: "redacted",
    clientSecret: "redacted",
    callbackURL: "/google/callback"
  },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
          const userQueryString = `
            SELECT firstName, lastName, AgentReference, agent_number, website_password, account_type, status, state, BIN(Flags) as flags 
            FROM compass.agent 
            WHERE googleID = ?`;
          console.log("google profile: \n", profile);
          //pull the user data for the agent with the same googleID as the selected accoutn at login.
          db.query(userQueryString,[profile.id],(err, response, fields)=>{
            if(err) {
              done(err);
            } else if(response.length === 0) {
              done(null, false);
            } else if(response[0].status === 'Terminated') {
              console.log('account is terminated.');
              done(null, false);
            } else {
              let user = {
                id: response[0].AgentReference
                , accountType: response[0].account_type
                , agent_number:response[0].agent_number
                , name:response[0].firstName + ' ' + response[0].lastName
                , state: response[0].state
                , flags: response[0].flags
              };
              let flagRegex = RegExp('^[0-1]*1[0-1]{9}$');
              if(flagRegex.test(user.flags)){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                return done(null, user);
              } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: "You do not have access to this feature. Please speak with your manager for more information."})
              }
            }
      });
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding  proxy:true to the google strategy fixed the issue for me. The callback URL was being sent to google as http instead of https because of this.